# python smallest number from list/array

Tags: python

Given an array of integers, remove the smallest value. Do not mutate the original array/list. If there are multiple elements with the same value, remove the one with a lower index. If you get an empty array/list, return an empty array/list.

Don't change the order of the elements that are left.

Example

```
remove_smallest([1,2,3,4,5]) = [2,3,4,5] 

remove_smallest([5,3,2,1,4]) = [5,3,2,4]

remove_smallest([2,2,1,2,1]) = [2,2,2,1]
```

This my code

```
def remove_smallest(numbers):  
    if numbers == []:
        raise NotImplementedError("TODO: remove_smallest")
    numbers = list(numbers)
    numbers.remove(min(numbers))
    return numbers
```

I'm having this trace back error `NotImplementedError("TODO: remove_smallest")`

Comment: Homework assignment?

Comment: if list is empty, just don't do anything...

Comment: Your code works fine for me. You must be passing it an empty array. But since you haven't showed what is actually giving the error, your post isn't doing a good job of explaining the problem in a way that we can help you.

Comment: If you don't understand why you are getting this error from that code you need to study Python more. Answering this question is sort of pointless if you can't figure out the basic question of where that error is coming from.

Comment: Ok, make a copy, I read the other way round...

Comment: I don't understand why you successfully achieve the hard parts and fail on the last easy bit.

Comment: 'If you get an empty array/list, return an empty array/list.'. You are not fulfilling this part of the problem - you are raising an exception.

Comment: (I suppose the code with the `TODO` part was given in the assignment)

Comment: @trincot yes! I deleted my comment. Mixed it with C++ `remove` function. I don't use that `remove` very much, probably because of that.

Comment: actually, it was an assignment. But if I may ask ? how can edit the code to return an empty list when given empty list

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. Plus what ever other error checking you want to accomplish.

```
def remove_smallest(numbers):
    if len(numbers) == 0:
        return numbers
    lowest = min(numbers)
    del numbers[numbers.index(lowest)]
    return numbers
```